# GeoJSON - Resymbolize without redownloading?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

GeoJSON served via GeoServer to OpenLayers.

Simple question - Is it possible to apply a new styleMap without redownloading the data from the server?

I am currently using the following, but am redownloading.

```
layer.styleMap = new_style
layer.refresh({force:true})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
layer.redraw();
```

It really is as simple as that.  `layer.refresh();` sends another request for the data to the backend, while the above command simply redraws the layer.  For my usage this is for a symbology change, but I'm sure others will have more interesting effects.